# retina ready image @2x not work

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, responsive

I read about retina ready sites and I get some information like In retina ready sites images, slider,font and other elements are more sharper, more density and high resolution...

**My Question is:**

How I convert Normal Site to Retina Ready with Images, Fonts and other things...

```
<img src="image1@2x.jpg" width="660" height="440"/>
```

> Original **width:** 660px and **height:** 440

And I already import retina.js

[Download RetinaJS from Here](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/)

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use high density images, you have to set another attribute : `srcset`.

In this way, `src` attribute is usefull for old browsers that don't support `srcset` attribute. `srcset` attribute is used by modern browsers that will use it in order to load high density "@2x" image if the screen is ready for it. If the screen is not retina, the browser will automaticly load the low density image "@1x".

```
<img srcset="image@1x.jpg 1x, image@2x.jpg 2x" src="image@1x.jpg" alt>
```

You can look at this article from MDN if you need more information about it. There are more attributes that can help you like `size`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: Actually, if you don't have retina or hd screen with you, it may be hard to test it. Maybe you have an modern smartphone like an iPhone or a Samsung Galaxy for exemple?  Retina and HD screen may be the same (depending on DPI). This one will display the retina picture.